# restrict sending mail to same sub domain for virtual users in postfix

Tags: postfix

I finished installing mail server with virtual users with centos dovecot and roundcube. Everything is working fine.

I want to restrict users from sending email to different sub domains.
How to achieve it. User can send email to same sub domain but not other sub domains.

Comment: is it possible to write header check like \n if (wild_card) sender_domain != receipient_domain REJECT email /^From:[[:space:]]+(.*)/ REPLACE From: ">${1}<" /^To

Comment: how to write regex for .         <br/> .      if (sender domain) != (Recipient domain) REJECT mail .           <br/>             /^From: != To:  REJECT